# Know who's the element with more Child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I XML document, with a votation. I have to know what's the propose with more votes, how can I do it? 
Im doing the transformation with XSLT and I can't find a way to do that.

XML:

```
<tns:vote>
  <tns:alternative>
    <tns:description>50% do valor recebido das propinas será aplicado em investigação</tns:description>
      <tns:votes>
        <tns:member_vote member_id="i2"/>
        <tns:member_vote member_id="i6"/>
        <tns:member_vote member_id="i7"/>
      </tns:votes>
    <tns:description>20% do valor recebido das propinas será aplicado em investigação</tns:description>
      <tns:votes>
        <tns:member_vote member_id="i4"/>
        <tns:member_vote member_id="i5"/>
      </tns:votes>
  </tns:alternative>        
</tns:vote>
```

In this example the first description should be the winner propose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution combines @Jirka 's XSLT 1.0 approach and my comment regarding multiple best votes and simply outputs a list of all best votes. It uses a preparation step to determine the best vote count and then in a second step selects all votes with best count. Note that in the second step we do not need to sort anymore. If required we could still do a sort though, if there is another sensible criterion breaking the symmetry of the best votes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:tns="mynamespace"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/tns:vote/tns:alternative">

    <!-- compute the best vote count; just the number not the elements -->
    <xsl:variable name="best_vote">
      <xsl:for-each select="tns:description">
        <xsl:sort select="count(following-sibling::tns:votes[1]/tns:member_vote)" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::tns:votes[1]/tns:member_vote)"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <tns:result>
      <xsl:for-each select="tns:description"> <!-- we need not sort here anymore! -->

        <!-- only dump those entries which match the best vote count -->
        <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::tns:votes[1]/tns:member_vote) = number($best_vote)">

          <tns:winning_vote vote_count="{count(following-sibling::tns:votes[1]/tns:member_vote)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::tns:votes[1]/tns:member_vote"/>
          </tns:winning_vote>

        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </tns:result>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

In xslt 1.0 you can use xsl:sort instruction like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tns="tns">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tns:vote/tns:alternative" />
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tns:alternative">
        <!-- Process all description -->
        <xsl:for-each select="tns:description">
            <!-- Sort them descending by count votes in the first following sibling tns:votes -->
            <xsl:sort select="count(following-sibling::tns:votes[1]/tns:member_vote)" order="descending" />
            <!-- Do anything with that, e.g. make a deep copy -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces xml with description sorted descending by votes.

If you need just one value ("winner") you could utilize e.g. `<xsl:if test="position() = 1">...</xsl:if>` inside for-each.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 you could use the `for-each-group` tag with a `sort`. The following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:tns="mynamespace"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/tns:vote/tns:alternative">

    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="tns:description">
      <xsl:sort select="count(current-group()[2]/tns:member_vote)" order="descending"/>

      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">

        <tns:winning_alternative vote_count="{count(current-group()[2]/tns:member_vote)}>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </tns:winning_alternative>

      </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

yields this result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <tns:winning_alternative xmlns:tns="mynamespace" vote_count="3">
   <tns:description>50% do valor recebido das propinas será aplicado em investigação</tns:description>
   <tns:votes>
      <tns:member_vote member_id="i2"/>
      <tns:member_vote member_id="i6"/>
      <tns:member_vote member_id="i7"/>
    </tns:votes>
</tns:winning_alternative>
```

Note that in case more than one alternative has equal best votes the XSLT will just pick one of them.

Comment: I need for XSLT 1.0 :s